# Can someone explain these lines for purpose of buffer and c strings

Tags: c++, c++11

```
getline(userfile, buffer);

new_user.birth_year = atoi(buffer.c_str());

for (stringstream s(buffer); s >> id;)
{
    new_user.friends.push_back(atoi(id.c_str()));
```

Answer (score 1):

> `getline(userfile, buffer);`

Reads in a line of text into the variable `buffer`.

> `new_user.birth_year = atoi(buffer.c_str());`

The `atoi` function requires a C-Style string.  The method `c_str()` returns a C-Style string from the `std::string`.
The `atoi` function converts a C-Style string to an integer.
The integer result is then assigned to `new_user.birth_year`.

> `for (stringstream s(buffer); s >> id;)`
>   `{`

The first part of the `for` loop, `stringstream s(buffer)`, creates a string stream from the `buffer` string.  The `stringstream` allows a string to be treated as a stream.

The `s >> id` reads a value from the string and places the result into `id`.

> `new_user.friends.push_back(atoi(id.c_str()));`

This line converts the `id` string to an integer (see above about `atoi`) and appends the integer to the vector `friends` inside the `new_user` object.

Comment: Do these line seem to buffer after a while? if so, why? getline(userfile, buffer); for (stringstream s(buffer); s >> id;) { new_user.friends.push_back(atoi(id.c_str())); } this->users.push_back(new_user); }

Comment: No, there is no buffering per se.  However, there may be delays in execution due to string variable reallocation.

Answer (score 0):

This apparently expects to read some data in a format something like this:

```
1992 17 3 34 9
```

The first number is a user's year of birth. The numbers after that are ID numbers of that person's friends.

The first bit (`new_user.birth_year = atoi(buffer.c_str());`) reads the first number and assigns it to `new_user.birth_year`.

The next loop reads the rest of the numbers and adds them to a collection (probably `std::vector`) holding the IDs of that user's friends. Minor probable bug: it looks like it adds their birth year as an ID of a friend, along with the rest of the IDs numbers.

Comment: @Mar: I'm not sure what: "Do these line seem to buffer after a while?" means. If you mean: "do they used buffered reading?" then yes. If something else..well, maybe you can clarify what you want to know.

Comment: The main reason for buffering is that doing a small read from a file typically has quite a bit of overhead, so instead of doing a lot of small reads, you typically want to do a few large reads, put the data into a buffer, then read small pieces from the buffer.